# How to run timer in the background even the app is killed in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-workmanager, flutter-background

I am trying to make the application send a notification when a specified period has elapsed, and this works well when the application is in the background, but when the application is closed, it does not do so, and I tried workmanager, but the problem remained the same

used workmanager to run timer in backgound and it failed

Comment: You could schedule a local notification that will allow your app to execute some code when that notification is received